# FFT Matlab on array (Example)

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, fft, nan

I'm trying to apply the FFT to an array of `4008x2` size. The data is imported from excel.

Just following the example that appears in [Mathworks](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html?refresh=true) they say if I have an array (matrix) then `fft(X)` treats the columns of `X` as vectors and returns the Fourier transform of each column.

I do that as follows

```
format long 
filename='Dean_Ignacio2.xls';
sheet=1;
xlRange='A9:B4008';

subsetA=xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange);
f=fft(subsetA);

plot(f)
```

but every element in the FFT appears as `NaN + NaNi`. What am I missing?

Comment: "Appears empty" - what is actual range? Have you tried plotting with log scaling?

Comment: for the entire array, for each position I receive this message back

NaN +               NaNi

as if the array was empty and the fft didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you apply [`fft`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) to a variable in MATLAB that contains any [`NaN`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) values then every value in the output of [`fft`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) will contain `NaN + NaNi`. [`NaN`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) stands for **Not a Number** and is most likely occurring because some of the data you are importing from your excel file is not valid numeric data that MATLAB can interpret. It could be as simple as the data being formatted as test in the excel file.

---

You can check if any of the values in your input matrix are `NaN` using [`any`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) and [`isnan`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html)

```
>> A = zeros(4008, 2);
>> A(randi(numel(A), 10)) = NaN; % Make 10 random values NaN
>> any(isnan(A))
ans =

     1     1
```

If `any(isnan(A))` returns `1` then at least 1 value in your input data is `NaN` and `fft(A)` will return `NaN + NaNi` for every element.

---

The [`xlsread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) function in MATLAB can return [numeric data, text data or the raw data](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthgbmn) from the excel file you are reading by using multiple output arguments. I suggest you use

```
>> [num, txt, raw] = xlsread(filename, sheet, xlRange);
```

to read the data from your excel file. You can then inspect the output to determine what it is that MATLAB is reading for each type. Numeric data will be in `num` (and is the same as `subsetA` in your question), text data will be in `txt` and the raw data will be in `raw`.